# How to checkbox in thymeleaf in accordance with the database through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, thymeleaf

How checked checkbox in Thymeleaf from JavaScript?

here I check if there is a substring `ROLE_USER` or `ROLE_ADMIN` in the line, and pass boolean to Thymeleaf in `th: checked`, but the checkboxes are not activated...

Checkbox in modal bootstrap:

```
th:checked="${checked}"
```

JavaScript:

```js
       var checked = false;
        if (userRoles.includes("ROLE_USER")) {
            checked = true;
            $("#modal-checkboxUser").val(checked);
            console.log(checked)
        }
        if (userRoles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
            checked = true;
            $("#modal-checkboxAdmin").val(checked);
            console.log(checked)
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `$("#modal-checkboxAdmin").prop('checked', true);` [.prop() | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2) ?

Comment: No, but thanks to your advice, I'll try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `prop("checked", {bool})`

```
$("#modal-checkboxUser").prop("checked", userRoles.includes("ROLE_USER")); 
$("#modal-checkboxAdmin").prop("checked", userRoles.includes("ROLE_ADMIN"));
console.log("ROLE_USER", $("#modal-checkboxUser").is(":checked"))
console.log("ROLE_ADMIN", $("#modal-checkboxAdmin").is(":checked"))
```